# $_product->hasCustomOptions() returns nothing [If a product has custom option]

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options

I am checking all the products in the cart, as if any of them contain custom options.

```
$items = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
    foreach ($items as $item) {
       echo $item->getId(); //prints ids eg. 427 429
       $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getId());
       if($_product->hasCustomOptions()){
              echo 'has custom option'; //doesn't print even the product has custom options
         }
     }
```

But the code above doesn't print "has option" even the product has. How to know if the product has custom option or not regardless of product type ?

Comment: I reckon you don't need to load the product here: you can try `$item->getProduct()->hasCustomOptions()` ?

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism , it printed. but it also printed for the product with configurable options. I want for only products with custom option.

Answer (score 0):

You have doing wrong.

It should be **`$item->getProductId()`** from **`$item->getId()`**.

***$item->getId()*** give u *cart item id* basically it given *sales_quote_item* table' primary  key field value   and `getProductId`() give you product id of item which you are cart.

So try this:

```
 $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
       if($_product->hasCustomOptions()){
              echo 'has custom option'; //doesn't print even the product has custom options
         }
```

Comment: It print's nothing. Rather `$item->getProduct()->hasCustomOptions()` prints but it's printing for both custom products as well as configurable products without custom options. ?

Comment: you have tried wrong,see the update

Comment: yeah, tried that exactly. `foreach ($items as $item) {
                           $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
                           if($_product->hasCustomOptions()){
                                  echo 'has custom option';
                             }
                         }` No result

Comment: is this given result or not?

Comment: No result. prints nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:

```
   $items = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
            foreach ($items as $item) {          
               $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
              $options = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_option')->getProductOptionCollection($_product);
$optionsSize = $options->getSize();
                  if($optionsSize){
                   echo 'has custom option'; //doesn't print even the product has custom options
                  }                           

            }
```

Comment: I don't have to check for product type. so i guess it's same.

Comment: Check updated answer.May be helpful to you

Comment: Please do not use this code in production. Loading objects in loops & collections is extremely bad code and will slow down your page load considerably.